# Singlespacing after section introduce additional space

Tags: line-spacing

With the package `setspace` I can change the line spacing. This works quite fine. When I place the command `\singlespacing` after a section it introduces additional space. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,bidi=basic,english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\onehalfspacing 
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
    \title{merry setspace christmas test}
    \author{who cares?}
    \date{2011-12-19}
    \maketitle
    \section{Kant - 1}
    \kant[1]
    \subsection{Kant - 2 }
    \singlespacing  % <----------------------------------
    \kant[2]
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: the code inserts a vskip there. Use \setstretch{1}.

Comment: Ahhh, OK, thx for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Put the `\singlespacing` before the `\subsection{Kant - 2}` not after it.

Comment: Although I agree with your approach I have the problem that I need to know in advance where the `\singlespacing` will be put to. I prefer more the approach that the command by itself should take care and not me as a user should take care where to place it.

Comment: @LeO It is you as the user who decides where to put `\singlespacing`. How do you expect the command to know where you really wanted it? ---GOM

Comment: But when using an environment with spacing the issue won't appear. So how does the environment knows but the command not? I know there is a diff but send quite strange.

Comment: @LeO (Change to) commands within an environment are local to the environment and do not apply outside it. This is standard (La)TeX.